# Wordpress FTP access

Tags: wordpress

First I had that problem that whenever I have to install any plugins, I have to put in my FTP details. I fixed it but now it says that could not create directory. Permission is set rightly but still

"Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/ftp-access.1.0.zip…

Unpacking the package…

Could not create directory."

Any help ?

Comment: That means your web server user doesn't have permissions to write to `wp-content/`. You probably need to change the owner or group.

Comment: check wp-content have 775 permission

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your WordPress folders permissions.
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18352747/524743) will take you to instructions how to do it right.